# Is there a way to take the output of a sample() in r and use it to index a character vector?

Tags: r, indexing

I am trying to generate random fake data for a project, I'm kind of at a loss. Been searching for about an hour. It's kind of a bootleg dictionary. Still very much learning and will definitely appreciate any constructive criticism in my logic.

Also, this is NOT my homework. This is something I am attempting to make my project easier. Im building a database using SQL and I want to create a CVS file but want to make data that works with best with what I am attempting.

```
J001 = c('Name1','Category1','SubCategory1','Purchase Amount1')
J002 = c('Name2','Category2','SubCategory2','Purchase Amount2')
J003 = c('Name3','Category3','SubCategory3','Purchase Amount3')
J004 = c('Name4','Category4','SubCategory4','Purchase Amount4')
...

products = c('J001','J002','J003','J004')

x_product = sample(products, 1)
x_Name = x_product[1] #Expecting 'Name'
```

Is this possible?

I've also tried sampling from a nested list in products but it returns different index values.

Edited a few variable names for clarity:
I would prefer a vector of strings because whatever sample picks from products; it will go into a column called ProductID.

The indexing for x_product[1] is necessary because I will eventually add each item in a J# object cell to a column.

Comment: There are a few things that are unclear here. (1) Do you have variables named `Name`, `Category`, etc, or are your `J#` objects here missing the quotes? (2) Is your `products` supposed to be a vector of strings or a list of objects? (3) You take `sample(products, 1)` and then use `[1]`, which seems wholly unnecessary. Could you please [edit] your question to make it more reproducible and clear? That is, if you cannot copy the code here and paste into your own R session (without errors or needing pre-existing variables), then it's harder for us to really follow your point.

Comment: @r2evans I apologize for being unclear. I have edited the question. I hope its a bit better explained. Thank you for time either way.

Comment: If I understand your goal, then you just need to remove the quotes around elements of `products`. ie, it should be `c(J001, J002, ...)`, not `c('J001', 'J002', ...)`.

Comment: @zephryl Thank you for the help. I actually attempted this before posting but the sample call returns a random cell value in any one of the J vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do what the question asks for.
First, see what is wrong with the way the posted code is trying to do it.

```r
J001 = c('Name1','Category1','SubCategory1','Purchase Amount1')
J002 = c('Name2','Category2','SubCategory2','Purchase Amount2')
J003 = c('Name3','Category3','SubCategory3','Purchase Amount3')
J004 = c('Name4','Category4','SubCategory4','Purchase Amount4')

# this is a character vector unrelated to the vectors above
products = c('J001','J002','J003','J004')

set.seed(2023)
# sample one element from the character vector 'products'
(x_product = sample(products, 1))
#> [1] "J001"
# the indexing is not needed, only one element was sampled
(x_Name = x_product[1]) # Expecting 'Name' 
#> [1] "J001"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Now the right way. [`mget`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html) searches for one or more objects by their names and returns their contents. The objects to be searched are the return value of [`ls`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ls.html).

```r
set.seed(2023)
# this is what creates an object holding the data above
products <- mget(ls(pattern = "^J\\d+", envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
# sample one member name from the list 'products'
x_product <- sample(names(products), 1)
# a name was extracted from the list, the indexing
# extracts the first element of that list
# a) wrong: returns a named sub-list
products[x_product]
#> $J001
#> [1] "Name1"            "Category1"        "SubCategory1"     "Purchase Amount1"
# b) right: extract the vector named 'x_product'
#           and then extract its first element
products[[x_product]][1]
#> [1] "Name1"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for bring this to my attention. I will learn up on mget. I think I can rewrite a lot of my generator using this and make it easier to read. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, **Rui Barradas**'s answer is correct, but I think it's better to bind your vectors as a dataframe, then use it for your customization
First, I create vectors, then bind them as dataframe:

```
J001 = c('Name1','Category1','SubCategory1','Purchase Amount1')
J002 = c('Name2','Category2','SubCategory2','Purchase Amount2')
J003 = c('Name3','Category3','SubCategory3','Purchase Amount3')
J004 = c('Name4','Category4','SubCategory4','Purchase Amount4')

# Combine them into a single data frame
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^J\\d+"))))
```

then, get rownames of your df as **products**, also set the colnames, then generate a sample of one of products, finally get name of this **sample** :

```
colnames(df) <- c("Name", "Category", "SubCategory", "Purchase.Amount")

products <- rownames(df)

x_product <- sample(products, 1)

x_Name <- df[x_product, "Name"]
```

also, you can add `drop = F` into `df[x_product, "Name", drop = F]` to keep rowname & colname (in other word, keep **x_name** as a dataframe)

Comment: I originally attempted the data frame route but without mget it didn't work. Im going to play around with this. Question: Is the pattern argument needed? I actually have products that use a different prefix than J.

Comment: If your global environment has only your products, then you don't need to pass pattern into `ls()`. I answered based on your question if you have different products as vector then you need to edit your question.